# KDE xdg-mime and random number

Tags: kde

From a few of days i have a problem with callto, tel or other link handler:
i have created a .desktop application and it has worked good:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=uriOpen CALLTO Handler
Exec=echo %u >> ~/testfile
#Exec=uriopen %U
Icon=plasma-mobile-phone
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/callto;
```

but... (commented Exec line is original command, my personal script), i have added new Exec line for debug and see output in a file.

Link for example is a simple html code as:

```
<p><a href="callto://4241">callto</a></p>
```

When i click in the link, Output in ~/testfile is:

```
0.0.16.145
```

?!?!
why this output? :((

**20231218 UPDATE:**
If i add a simple character at the beginning, it works.
ex. `callto://n4241`
in my launcher script i've add a sed that delete **n** character.

I suspect a KDE XDG-MIME problem?!

Version:
kde plasma = 5.27.10
KDE Frameworks = 5.112.0
Qt = 5.15.11
Kernel = 6.6.4-MANJARO (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 3986 [1], an URI is:

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-rootless
              / path-empty
authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
path-rootless = segment-nz *( "/" segment )
```

So "4241" is parsed as `authority` which is basically a host.

Number 4241 in base 10 translate to base 16 as 00001091, which map back to 0.0.16.145.

More likely "4241" is intented as a path, so just use a single "/" (`path-absolute`) or none at al (`path-rootless`).

[1] https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3

Comment: Thanks André.


Then why if i add a simple character as 'n', it works?! 

ex. <command callto://n4241>

t'is still authority, no?

And if i launch from command line as:

<command callto://4241>

it works!!

i suspect problem was in KDE XGD-mime...

Comment: @scaldezu n4241 looks like a hostname that's already normalized. If it looks like a hostname it could work, but other times it won't.